# Why is VRFConsumerBaseV2(vrfCoordinator) in the constructor declaration?

Tags: solidity, chainlink, constructor

I am new to Solidity and going through Patrick Collins' online course. In the following code, I was wondering why `VRFConsumerBaseV2(vrfCoordinator)` is included in the constructor declaration. I thought that function declarations only included things like modifiers and visibility.

```
constructor(uint64 subscriptionId) VRFConsumerBaseV2(vrfCoordinator) {
  COORDINATOR = VRFCoordinatorV2Interface(vrfCoordinator);
  LINKTOKEN = LinkTokenInterface(link);
  s_owner = msg.sender;
  s_subscriptionId = subscriptionId; 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The contract you're writing is *implementing* (extending/inheriting from) `VRFConsumerBaseV2`.  That is not a function declaration - in fact you've noted that it is a constructor declaration which is a bit different.

In solidity, constructors can instantiate the parent class using this syntax that you've referred to.
See [the docs here](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/latest/contracts.html#arguments-for-base-constructors).

This particular style that you're referring to employs a modifier of the derived constructor.  It's similar to modifier functions on regular functions, but different because these are used in constructor functions which are a sub-type of regular functions.

Comment: Oh I see, I wasn't understanding the syntax. Thanks!